# Audio jack i/o nonworking

Tags: sound

The Headphone Jack works but the audio jack i/o on the motherboard doesn't work on Ubuntu.
VIA VT2021

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. I have deleted your second question, please ask it again separately. Also, please [edit] your question and give us information about your hardware, explain how you check whether it works and describe how exactly it fails.

Comment: did you run `sudo update-grub`? this may fix the partition issue. Also, have you tried running the command `alsamixer` to manage your audio?

Comment: MY audio chip set is VIA VT2021.

Comment: That didn't help